# Isomorphism vs. equivalence of types and homotopy vs. equality of functions

Tags: type-theory, homotopy-type-theory, univalent-foundations

I am trying to build an understanding of the Univalence Axiom in HoTT and I am slightly confused about some definitions.

If I was asked after reading of Chapter 1 of the HoTT book to formulate a definition for the type of equivalences $A \simeq B$, I would write something like this:

$$A \cong B := \sum_{f : A \to B} \sum_{g : B \to A} (f \circ g = 1_{B}) \times (g \circ f = 1_{A})$$

which we might call “naive isomorphism of types”. The author explains that this is not the preferred definition for two reasons:

1. Functional equality is unnecessary when compared to the *a priori* weaker notion than pointwise equality (i.e. homotopy), so we replace the $=$ with $\sim$ signs.
2. That the left and right-inverse necessarily coincide is coincidental and it is equivalent to ask for the left and right-inverse exist independently.

The definition is therefore given as follows:

$$A \simeq B := \sum_{f : A \to B} \left(\sum_{g : B \to A} f \circ g \sim 1_{B}\right) \times \left(\sum_{h : B \to A} h \circ f \sim 1_{A}\right).$$

On the other hand, we know that univalence implies functional extensionality (i.e. the types $f \sim g$ and $f = g$ are equivalent), and it is quite clear that

$$\left(\sum_{g : B \to A} f \circ g \sim 1_{B}\right) \times \left(\sum_{h : B \to A} h \circ f \sim 1_{A}\right) \quad \text{and} \quad \sum_{g : B \to A} (f\circ g \sim 1_{B}) \times(g \circ f \sim 1_A)$$

are equivalent as well (albeit the latter is supposedly less well behaved). The upshot is that $A \cong B$ and $A \simeq B$ are equivalent, under univalence. This leads me to wonder what would go wrong if we took $\cong$ to be the standard notion of equivalence and formulated the Univalence Axiom accordingly. Certainly, for me, the definition of $\cong$ is slightly more intuitive because it is verbatim the same notion as in 1-categories and needs not be motivated by homotopy theory or higher categories. But I'm guessing there is a good reason that things are presented in the way they are.

Answer (score 5):

It turns out that
$$
\operatorname{isequiv}(f)
\equiv
\left( 
  \sum_{g : B \to A}
  f \circ g \sim 1_{B}
\right)
\times
\left(
  \sum_{h : B \to A}
  h \circ f \sim 1_{A}
\right)
$$
and
$$
\operatorname{qinv}(f)
\equiv
\sum_{g : B \to A}
(f \circ g \sim 1_{B})
\times
(g \circ f \sim 1_{A})
$$
are not actually equivalent.  This is mentioned briefly in Section 2.4, and Chapter 4 gives a proof.  More explicitly, Theorem 4.1.3 gives an example of a function $f : A \to B$ such that $\operatorname{qinv}(f)$ is not a mere proposition, while Theorem 4.3.2 proves that $\operatorname{isequiv}(f)$ is a mere proposition.  So $\operatorname{isequiv}(f)$ and $\operatorname{qinv}(f)$ cannot be equivalent.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. Actually it's surprising because there seem to be obvious functions $\textrm{isequiv(f)} \to \textrm{qinv(f)}$ and vice versa which I assumed to form an equivalence but I admit that I didn't check at the time of writing the question.

Do you know what goes wrong if we replace $\sim$ with $=$ in $\textrm{isequiv}$?

Comment: There are natural functions in both directions, but the composite $\operatorname{qinv}(f) \to \operatorname{isequiv}(f) \to \operatorname{qinv}(f)$ needn't be the identity.  In the presence of funext, the versions of $\operatorname{isequiv}(f)$ with $\sim$ and $=$ are equivalent, so you could use either.  I don't know for sure why the authors privilege $\sim$, but the reason I would do so is that it's hard to get terms of type $=$ without assuming some kind of extensionality axiom (e.g., funext, univalence, ...).  So $\sim$ is better behaved in the general situation.

Comment: Even more is true: trying to formulate univalence with qinv is actually inconsistent.  This is exercise 4.6.